# Accessing another SQL Server's stored procedure from my stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

Is there anyway to access the stored procedure (which is located in another SQL Server in another PC) in my stored procedure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, but sql server located on another PC must be connected as a [linked server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx).
 Please see:
[SQL SERVER – Executing Remote Stored Procedure – Calling Stored Procedure on Linked Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/06/sql-server-executing-remote-stored-procedure-calling-stored-procedure-on-linked-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the servers are linked, you can call the second stored procedure using the four-part name.

EXEC SecondaryServerName.SomeDatabase.schema.P_Super_Awesome_Procedure_Name @MyParameter

See Also: [Setting Up A Linked SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)